# How to parse "invisible" to html items with jsoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get all restaurant reviews from hardens.com via jsoup but I have a problem. By default on each restaurant you can see 3 reviews which also appear on the page source. If there are more reviews available, there is a "Load More Reviews" option which allows me to see the reviews via my browser but when I view the page page source they aren't there. There is not a link for the "Load More Reviews" and I don't know how am I supposed to get those reviews. Any ideas?

Here is a link from that website:
http://www.hardens.com/az/restaurants/london/w1/le-gavroche.htm

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code and clarify your issue?  It doesn't sound like what you are trying to do is something you should be doing for many reasons.

Comment: I have tried to find a link which would contain those reviews with no luck. I don't think that the code would matter, the most important thing is to find the right method to get the missing content. What I am trying to do was assigned to me for my thesis :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that site is loading in the additional reviews via an AJAX request. Looking at the console with XHR logging enabled, I see:

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://www.hardens.com/more_reviews/load_more_reviews.php".
```

So you need to figure out what JS code is running that request and run the same request yourself. It probably returns JSON or something similarly machine-readable, so you might be able to use that PHP script as an easier alternative to scraping.